# Integrating Chartboost to Swift

Tags: ios, swift, chartboost

I have integrated all the chartboost the from https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/201220095-iOS-Integration

but I'm keep getting these 18 errors in my chartboost.h file.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7Xek.png

I'm not sure if I made my AppDelegate.swift correct to integrate swift?

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, ChartboostDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let kChartboostAppID = "559f1b52c909a64f054eb563";
    let kChartboostAppSignature = "41ad09b1bd90bbf3b3712d9530f45daff3fbd04f";

    Chartboost.startWithAppId(kChartboostAppID, appSignature: kChartboostAppSignature, delegate: self)
    Chartboost.setShouldRequestInterstitialsInFirstSession(false)



    return true

}

func showChartboostAds()
{
    Chartboost.showInterstitial(CBLocationHomeScreen);

}

func didFailToLoadInterstitial(location :String!, withError error: CBLoadError)
{

}

func didDismissInterstitial(location :String! )
{
    if(location == CBLocationHomeScreen)
    {
        Chartboost.cacheInterstitial(CBLocationMainMenu)
    }
    else if(location == CBLocationMainMenu)
    {
        Chartboost.cacheInterstitial(CBLocationGameOver)
    }
    else if(location == CBLocationGameOver)
    {
        Chartboost.cacheInterstitial(CBLocationLevelComplete)
    }
    else if(location == CBLocationLevelComplete)
    {
        Chartboost.cacheInterstitial(CBLocationHomeScreen)
    }
}
```

please help i have been stuck here for a while now please can you help?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same the problem. I brought the entire Chartboost folder into my project instead of just the framework. Go into the folder and delete ChartboostExample. There's an example Xcode project in there that seems to causing weird things to happen.